# [Prometheus]Couldn't load silences

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, alert, prometheus

I configure alermanager.conf:

```
notification_config {
    name: "alert_test"
    email_config {
        email: "annt@gmail.com"
    }
}
aggregation_rule {
  repeat_rate_seconds: 3600
  notification_config_name: "alert_test"
}
```

Then, I execute command: `./alertmanager -config.file alertmanager.conf` and it displays notice:

```
 Couldn't load silences, starting up with empty silence list: open silences.json: no such file or directory  file=main.go line=81
```

how to fix this error???
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning that it can't find the silence file, this is normal the first time you start the alertmanager and haven't created any silences yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And I have a question. I configure postfix null-client and set -notification.smtp.smarthost:25 , but Alert doesn't send to mail. It notice "starttsl failed" and require authentication